# How does unRAID enable http://tower?

Tags: ip-address

You can see in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9prjO3Qq1s at 10:55 that Linus enters http://tower into the browser, and the webGUI loads. How does unRAID do that? Does one have to set it as a DNS server, or how can such a locally available url be created, if I want to have a linux server have a similar name?

Edit: Synology is doing a similar thing with http://diskstation:5000

It somehow acts as a DNS server to tell the computer its IP address.
On a Mac for example, typing `host -a diskstation` into Terminal shows the local IP of the NAS.